# CNF form of the logical $atleast(b) x_{i,k}$

Tags: logic, mixed-integer-programming, linearization, conjunctive-normal-form

Suppose there exists the following logical expression:

$$(\sum_{i=1}^I x_{(i,k)} \leq b) \implies (z_{(j,k)}=1) \quad \forall j \in J, k \in K \tag{1}$$

where all of variables, $x_{(i,k)}$ and $z_{(j,k)}$, are binary. I know this logical form can easily be translated into its linear form by $BigM$ formulation. However, as all of the variables are binary, I guess, there should be a purely logical form translation based on $CNF/DNF$ to convert that. What I have tried is:

$$(\text{atmost(b)}_i x_{(i,k)}) \implies  (z_{(j,k)}=1) \quad \forall j \in J, k \in K \quad => $$
$$(\lnot \text{atmost(b)}_i x_{(i,k)}) \lor(z_{(j,k)})   \quad \forall j \in J, k \in K \quad => $$
$$(\text{atleast(b+1)}_i x_{(i,k)}) \lor(z_{(j,k)})   \quad \forall j \in J, k \in K \quad => $$
$$\bigwedge (\bigvee x_{(i,k)}) \lor(z_{(j,k)})   \quad \forall j \in J, k \in K \quad => $$

At the moment, I am not sure how can I transform the first clause of the last expression and am wondering if, someone can advise me.

P.S: The ***atleast*** expression can be written as the following form:

$$ atleast(k)_{i} x_{i}  \iff \bigwedge_{S \subset I | | S|=n-k+1} (\bigvee_{i \in S} x_{i}) $$

And the first $\bigwedge_{S}$ is where I am getting stuck to explode the related sets.

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, would you please, take a look at this?

Comment: Do you also need the inverse (sum $>b$ implies $z=0$)?

Comment: How should we read the last line of your progression (conjunction over what of the disjunction over what of what)?

Comment: Dear @prubin, I will add some details in my question. Thanks 

Comment: Dear @prubin, sorry for my late. I just updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, omit the $j$ and $k$ indices.  You want to enforce $$\sum_i x_i \le b \implies z=1.\tag1\label1$$  As you mentioned, a natural approach is the big-M formulation $$b+1-\sum_i x_i \le Mz,$$ and you can take $M=b+1$, yielding $$\sum_i x_i + (b+1)z \ge b+1 \tag2\label2.$$  For CNF, you can instead first rewrite \eqref{1} as
$$\left(\sum_i x_i \ge b+1\right) \lor z.$$  Now think of all the $(b+1)$-subsets $S$ of $\{1,\dots,I\}$ and rewrite as
$$\left(\bigvee_{S:|S|=b+1} \bigwedge_{i\in S} x_i\right) \lor z,$$
equivalently,
$$\left(\bigwedge_{T:|T|=I-b} \bigvee_{i\in T} x_i\right) \lor z,$$
equivalently,
$$\bigwedge_{T:|T|=I-b} \left(\bigvee_{i\in T} x_i \lor z\right),$$
which yields linear constraints
$$\sum_{i\in T} x_i + z \ge 1 \quad \text{for all $T$ such that $|T|=I-b$}.\tag3\label3$$
Notice that aggregating \eqref{3} yields
$$
\sum_{T:|T|=I-b} \left(\sum_{i\in T} x_i + z\right) \ge \sum_{T:|T|=I-b} 1 \\
\sum_{T:|T|=I-b} \sum_{i\in T} x_i + \binom{I}{I-b}z \ge \binom{I}{I-b} \\
\binom{I-1}{I-b-1} \sum_{i=1}^I x_i + \binom{I}{I-b}z \ge \binom{I}{I-b} \\
\binom{I-1}{b} \sum_{i=1}^I x_i + \binom{I}{b}z \ge \binom{I}{b} \\
\sum_{i=1}^I x_i + \frac{I}{I-b}z \ge \frac{I}{I-b},
$$
but this aggregation is generally weaker than \eqref{2}.

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, sorry for my late, and also thanks for your reply. Actually, I could drive constraint $3$, but I cannot explode the sets in the $\text{T}$. Would you please, explain more on how we can interpret the sets $S$ and $T$, and also their relation to $I$?

Comment: Also, if you mean by $I$ is something like the card of $I$, the last expression is very similar to a $BigM$ form. May I have your insight?

Comment: The logical expression just before (3) is the CNF you requested. Yes, $I$ is the cardinality of the index set for $x_i$, just like in your initial sum $\sum_{i=1}^I$. Sometimes CNF has an exponential number of terms, and I don’t see any way to avoid that here if you don’t want to use auxiliary variables. The final big-M constraint was just an aside to see whether aggregation would yield a tighter formulation than (2).

Comment: If your concern is that (2) is weak and (3) is exponentially large, you could impose (2) and then generate (3) dynamically (row generation).  The separation problem for (3) is easy: you can find the most violated $T$ (if any) just by sorting $x^*$ and taking the smallest $I-b$ entries.

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, many thanks for detailed explanation. Please, let me think more about this, specifically, the last expressions you commented out and I will back to you. 

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, I am not sure to understand what is a reason to change $\bigvee_{S:|S|=b+1}$ into $\bigwedge_{T:|T|=I-b}$. Would you please, explain a bit more?

Comment: Also, for aggregation what does $\binom{I}{I-b}$ mean?

Comment: For CNF, you want the $\land$ on the outside, so that is the motivation to rewrite with $\land_T$. The $\binom{I}{I-b}$ is a binomial coefficient that counts the number of such subsets.

Comment: is the CNF form I mentioned in my question the same as what you mentioned exactly one line before linear constraint number (3)? If so, can it yield the same expression you derived in the last line?

Comment: The binomial coefficient is so new to me. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Yes, for the CNF you added later to your question as a P.S., if you change $S$ to $T$ and $k$ to $b+1$ and also incorporate the $\lor z$, you obtain the same CNF from my answer.

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, thanks so much as I have learned a lot from you. 

Answer (score 1):

Since the $\bigwedge$ and $\bigvee$ don't have anything to do with the $j$ and $k$, you can use Distribution to go from:

$$\bigwedge (\bigvee x_{(i,k)}) \lor(z_{(j,k)})   \quad \forall j \in J, k \in K \quad $$

to:

$$\bigwedge \left((\bigvee x_{(i,k)}) \lor(z_{(j,k)})\right)   \quad \forall j \in J, k \in K \quad $$

Also: So far I have just paid attention to your last expression… but now that I am looking at the one before it: I think you should swap the $\bigwedge$ and $\bigvee$, to capture all possible ways (thus $\bigvee$) to get at least $b+1$ terms $x_{(i,k)}$ (thus $\bigwedge$). Of course, with that, my Distribution above is unnecessary and in fact the resulting formula is in DNF already

Comment: thanks. I am not sure to understand what you proposed. Do you mean is something like $\bigwedge (x_{(i,k)} \lor z_{(j,k)})   \quad \forall j \in J, k \in K \quad$?

Comment: @A.Omidi Aye, sorry, I misread your formula ... ignore my earlier Answer!

Comment: @A.Omidi OK, changed my Answer :P

Comment: Dear @Bram28, I will add some details in my question. Thanks 